# "A" is about as much "B" as "C" is "D"

Tags: phrases

I wanna find out what this sentence means.

“ASOT is about as much “trance” as Nelson Mandela is indie punk.”

So to generalize:

"A" is about as much "B" as "C" is "D"

Is this comparing A with B? Is this being sarcasm?

Comment: OK. First, measure the degree to which "Nelson Mandela" is "indie rock". This sentence says that that degree is the same as the degree to which "ASOT' is "trance". One presumes -- unless there is an indie rock band named "Nelson Mandela" -- that the degree is zero, and so it's a long confusing way to say that "ASOT" is **not** "trance". If this makes sense to you, good; it's nice that it makes sense to somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences of this type commonly serve as a form of dismissive argument, based on the tactic of equating a proposed quality of a person or thing with an absurd imagined quality of another person or thing. The effect is to ridicule the original proposal. Such formulations often involve a sarcastic element as well.

Answer (score 3):

When saying "A is about as much B as C is D", one is saying that A = B only to the extent that C = D. Or, more accurately, one is saying that A is unlike B as much as C is unlike D. In other words, one is contrasting A and B by using a second negative comparison for emphasis.

For instance, let's say someone walks inside a store from the parking lot and comments that "It's so hot outside!". Here, A = "It" (the weather) and B = the property of being hot.

If someone else disagrees with them, that person might say something to the effect of, "It's about as hot outside as the ocean is dry": A = It (the temperature outside), B = the property of being hot, C = the ocean, D = the property of being dry. What is meant by this sentence is that it is *not* hot outside, just like the ocean is not dry.

It can also be used in an insulting or mock-insulting manner; for instance, among a group of friends, one member might comment that, "That musical group is very talented!" If another member disagrees, they might snidely remark that "That musical group is about as talented as your face is pretty." Here, they are showing both their disagreement with the original comment and implying that the original speaker is unattractive.

Note, too, that occasionally the same construction is used to compare two pairs of items favorably. For example, one might say about a young child who is introduced to a new activity and shows an aptitude for it, "He takes to that activity like a duck (or fish) takes to water."